# why my celery task is not executing periodically?

Tags: django, django-views, celery, django-celery

I have a celery periodic task but the task run only when either I run celery worker or I run celery beat. I have configured the task to run every 20 minutes in django `settings.py` file but after I check after 20 minutes the celery worker doesn't receive any task.

celery beat console

```
celery beat v4.4.4 (cliffs) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2020-07-16 12:10:18
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
[2020-07-16 12:10:18,835: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
```

When I exit this beat and again restart then the celery worker receives the task immediately and executes.

**I want the celery worker to receive and execute the task periodically every 20 minutes.How can I do this ?**

I run the celery worker and celery beat in two different console.
I used commands
`celery -A myproj worker -l info` for worker
`celery -A myproj beat -l info --pidfile=` for beat

tasks.py

```
app = Celery('myproj')
@app.task
def schedule_task():
    running_tasks = Task.objects.filter(Q(status=0) | Q(status=1))
    print(running_tasks)
    for task in running_tasks:
        unique_id = task.unique_id
        keywords = task.keywords.all()
        if task.scraping_end_date > timezone.now().date():
            settings = {
                'spider_count': len(task.targets.all()),
                'keywords': keywords,
                'scraping_end': task.scraping_end_date,
                'unique_id': unique_id,  # unique ID for each record for DB
                'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
            }

            for site_url in task.targets.all():
                domain = urlparse(site_url.domain).netloc
                spider_name = domain.replace('.com', '')
                task = scrapyd.schedule('default', spider_name, settings=settings,
                                        url=site_url.domain, domain=domain, keywords=keywords)
              
        else:
            task.status = 2
            task.save()
```

settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'crawl_sites': {
    'task': 'crawler.tasks.schedule_task',
    'schedule': crontab(minute='*/20'),
},
```

}

Comment: how do you run it ? pass `-B` parameter to the celery beat

Comment: start worker and beat in one call, set log level to debug and since you use django, try `celery -A myproj worker --beat --loglevel=debug --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler`

Answer (score 3):

Replace the line

```
'schedule': crontab(minute=20),
```

to

```
'schedule': crontab(minute='*/20'),
```

Also restart celery beat.

Comment: didn't worked. Is there any other things that might be missing ?

Comment: I need to restart the celery beat every time and then only the celery worker receives the task and executes. Why is this happening?